# redirect website to VPS, but other DNS records remain in Cpanel host

Tags: dns, vps, cpanel

I want to redirect my website to a VPS, but remain all other things like mail server in my CPanel host.

In zone editor, I define an A record that points to my my VPS and a CName for www

```
mydomain.com.   14400   A   VPS_IP_ADDRESS
mydomain.com.   14400   CNAME   mydomain.com
mail.mydomain.com.  14400   A   CPANEL_HOST_IP_ADDRESS
```

and website works with this approach, but email not works!

Actually I can send email from Roundcube on my webmail, but I can't receive email (on both webmail and outlook) and Also I can send email from my outlook!

Full List of DNS records:

```
mydomain.com.   14400   A   VPS_IP_ADDRESS
 
mydomain.com.   14400   MX  Priority: 0 Destination: mydomain.com
 
www.mydomain.com.   14400   CNAME   mydomain.com
 
ftp.mydomain.com.   14400   CNAME   mydomain.com
 
webdisk.mydomain.com.   14400   A   CPANEL_HOST_IP_ADDRESS
 
cpcontacts.mydomain.com.    14400   A CPANEL_HOST_IP_ADDRESS
 
whm.mydomain.com.   14400   A   CPANEL_HOST_IP_ADDRESS
 
cpanel.mydomain.com.    14400   A   CPANEL_HOST_IP_ADDRESS
 
cpcalendars.mydomain.com.   14400   A   CPANEL_HOST_IP_ADDRESS
 
webmail.mydomain.com.   14400   A   CPANEL_HOST_IP_ADDRESS
 
default._domainkey.mydomain.com.    14400   TXT VALUE
mydomain.com.   14400   TXT v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:CPANEL_HOST_IP_ADDRESS ~all   
 
mailpoet1._domainkey.mydomain.com.  14400   CNAME   dkim1.sendingservice.net
 
mailpoet2._domainkey.mydomain.com.  14400   CNAME   dkim2.sendingservice.net
 
_mailpoet.mydomain.com. 14400   TXT VALUE
_cpanel-dcv-test-record.mydomain.com.   14400   TXT _cpanel-dcv-test-record=VALUE
_acme-challenge.mydomain.com.   14400   TXT VALUE
_acme-challenge.mydomain.com.   14400   TXT VALUE
mail.mydomain.com.  14400   A   CPANEL_HOST_IP_ADDRESS
 
mydomain.com.   14400   TXT google-site-verification=VALUE
```

Comment: Your use of a CNAME at the origin level for the domain  is invalid and likely breaking your setup. Remove it. Do you have any neefs other then mail and web? Where are your MX records? Is using a catchall record (*) to point to the IP of your cpanel IP an option?

Comment: It seems like you misunderstand DNS and mail configuration.  Im not sure answering the question you actually asked is helpful to you - but **the highly misleading-but-technically-correct answer is you can't**. If multiple resources require different A records for the same host name you need to change the hostname associated with some resources or proxy the requests through a server outside of DNS.  Note that **mail does not require an A record for the domain to work.** You really need to be using MX records to reference mail servers. (which can point to a subdomain with an a record)

Comment: Thanks @davidgo 
I edited the question to show you full dns records list.
In past, I was handling whole website and mail records in VPS, but because of my weakness in handling VPS in front of attacks, I decided to use of CPanel for email and other things and use of VPS just for website.

Comment: The answer from @davidgo is right. Since your current MX record simply points to `mydomain.com` it'll be working... except now that you've pointed `mydomain.com` to the VPS the emails will be getting sent there (and presumably being rejected), NOT your cPanel server. So since you already have `mail.mydomain.com` configured if you point the MX there the email will be sent to the correct destination again.

Answer (score 2):

To change your underlying problem (based on the full list of DNS records) you need to change your MX record (the second record you have listed)  so the destination is "mail.mydomain.com" rather then "mydomain.com".

Additionally you need to check - and if necessary update - all email clients and change any reference to "mydomain.com" to "mail.mydomain.com" - you should check this is correct for both SMTP and IMAP/POP3 settings.   If it already states "mail.mydomain.com" it is OK.  I expect that Roundcube will be using webmail.mydomain.com and this can be left as-is.

Because your TTL's are set quite high at 14400 you will need to wait up to 12 hours after changing your DNS before you can correctly receive email from everywhere.  (If you are uncertain of yourself and you can, you may want to change the TTL records from 14400 to 3600 or even lower so changes come into effect within an hour - it is common when modifying DNS for you to even have these values much shorter and then once everything is working increase them.  The 14400 is the time to cache the DNS information in seconds - so 300 equates to 5 minutes)

(I trust you have removed the CNAME associated with mydomain.com listed in the top/original part of the question)

Comment: Thanks for your great help, @davidgo . Is your purpose of CNAME was for www.mydomain.com. ? So what will happen for www of my website? Do I need to add an A record instead of it?

Comment: CNAMES are weird and don't behave quite as expected.  If using an A record is practical it is preferable as it acts as you would expect and requires  only 1 lookup as opposed to 2.  That said, for the www subdomain it is fine to use a CNAME if you want to.(999 times out of 1000 using a CNAME for just subdomain.com - without the www - is wrong though)